# Applying transformations to dataframes with multi-level indices in Python's pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to do apply simple functions to mostly numeric data in pandas. the data is a set of matrices indexed by time. I wanted to use hierarchical/multilevel indices to represent this and then use a split-apply-combine like operation to group the data, apply an operation, and summarize the result as a dataframe. I'd like the result of these operations to be dataframes and not Series objects.

Below is a simple example with two matrices (two time points) represented as a multi level dataframe. I want to subtract a matrix from each time point, then collapse the data by taking the mean, and get back a dataframe that preserves the original column names of the data.

Everything I try either fails or gives an odd result. I tried to follow http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html since this is basically a split-apply-combine operation, I think, but the documentation is very hard to understand and the examples are dense.

How can this be achieved in pandas? I annotated where my code fails along the relevant lines:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

t1 = pandas.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 1, 1],
                       [5, 5, 5]], columns=[1, 2, 3], index=["A", "B", "C"])
t2 = pandas.DataFrame([[10, 10, 30],
                       [5, 1, 1],
                       [2, 2, 2]], columns=[1, 2, 3], index=["A", "B", "C"])
m = np.ones([3,3])
c = pandas.concat([t1, t2], keys=["t1", "t2"], names=["time", "name"])
#print "c: ", c

# How to view just the 'time' column values?
#print c.ix["time"]  # fails
#print c["time"] # fails

# How to group matrix by time, subtract value from each matrix, and then
# take the mean across the columns and get a dataframe back?
result = c.groupby(level="time").apply(lambda x: np.mean(x - m, axis=1))

# Why does 'result' appear to have TWO "time" columns?!
print result

# Why is 'result' a series and not a dataframe?
print type(result)

# Attempt to get a dataframe back
df = pandas.DataFrame(result)

# Why does 'df' have a weird '0' outer (hierarchical) column??
print df
#                         0
# time time name
# t1   t1   A     -1.000000
#           B     -0.333333
#           C      4.000000
# t2   t2   A     15.666667
#           B      1.333333
#           C      1.000000
```

In short, the operation I'd like to do is:

```
for each time point:
  subtract m from time point matrix
  collapse the result matrix across the columns by taking the mean (preserving the row labels "A", "B", "C"
return result as dataframe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to view just the 'time' column values?

```
In [11]: c.index.levels[0].values
Out[11]: array(['t1', 't2'], dtype=object)
```

> how to group matrix by time, subtract value from each matrix, and then
>   take the mean across the columns and get a dataframe back?

Your attempt was pretty close:

```
In [46]: c.groupby(level='time').apply(lambda x: x - m).mean(axis=1)
Out[46]: 
time  name
t1    A       -1.000000
      B       -0.333333
      C        4.000000
t2    A       15.666667
      B        1.333333
      C        1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks but your solution still returns a series. I'd like to have a dataframe back. also can you explain the difference between your call and mine? if I try ```pandas.DataFrame(c.groupby(level='time').apply(lambda x: x - m).mean(axis=1))``` I still get the weird extra column "0" as outer column/index

Comment: @lgd Without an explicit column name, the DataFrame get a default column name of `0`. You can supply a name via `pandas.DataFrame(..., columns=['something_here'])`.

Comment: I give the columns the names [1, 2, 3] when defining the dataframes ``t1`` and ``t2``